# How to send ^K to shell

Tags: shell, applescript, control-characters

I want to run a shell command in Terminal, then clear the console, from Applescript.

If I was doing this by hand, I'd use ^K -- how do I send the ^K character in a string to Terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the gent who suggested 'clear' probably has the issue solved, but just in case you actually want to do what you said you did, you can simply use:

echo "^L"

(you type this as 'echo ""')

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for the 'clear' command.